# Detect if it's lilo boot loader or grub?

Tags: arch-linux, grub, lilo

Without rebooting, is it possible to tell if the boot loader currently present was LILO. GRUB 0.97 or GRUB 1.9X?

I was thinking about reading MBR, but not sure about it.  Just by checking the files on system, i.e /etc/lilo.conf doesn't testify anything

Any ideas?

Comment: And if it's not in the MBR then that won't work anyways.

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: @jippie Arch, and I think it doesn't matter ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use grep on your MBR to figure out:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep GRUB
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep LILO
```

Only one of those should return a match.

For more information and other ways to figure out, check [this answer in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24459/how-do-i-find-out-which-boot-loader-i-have).

Comment: I wasn't expecting strings in the MBR, that was awesome!