# Is the EFI boot loader not in MBR?

Tags: boot, grub, boot-loader, gummiboot

Based on [this answer for detecting the boot loader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58626/3645) I ran `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 2>&1 | grep GRUB` and it matched. However, I'm pretty sure I'm running Gummiboot since [modifying `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode#Enabling_Intel_Microcode_Updates) affected my boot. Does an EFI boot loader like Gummiboot not modify the MBR, or am I misunderstanding something? Is it a problem if I have "enabled" both?

Related to [enabling Intel microcode updates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163732/how-to-enable-intel-microcode-updates-with-gummiboot-on-arch-linux).

Comment: The EFI boot loader is in its own partition, type EF00, formatted vfat. The EFI loader resides on the filesystem, but isn't necessarily in the first N blocks. What is it you want to do?

Comment: ^this. and, in fact, it is extremely rare that you would even have an MBR if you are booting with EFI as you are almost definitely working with a GPT-formatted disk per spec - though I have recently been made aware that MBR+EFI is possible. maybe look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146803/52934) for a short-discussion on EFI boot process, and definitely look at [rodsbooks.com](http://rodsbooks.com)

Comment: Were you referring to a specific book or article at rodsbooks.com?

Comment: There are several series which you'll find under *My Web Pages* but [Managing EFI BootLoaders for Linux](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) is as good a place as any to start. The other link I provided before is really just a primer for rodsbooks, anyway, and also contains a few relevant links to various pages there.