# How to enable Intel Microcode updates with Gummiboot on Arch Linux?

Tags: gummiboot

After following [the instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode#Enabling_Intel_Microcode_Updates) the boot process halted saying it couldn't find `intel-ucode.img`.

The package is installed:

```
$ pacman --query --info intel-ucode | head -n1
Name           : intel-ucode
```

Gummiboot is configured:

```
$ cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf
title Arch Linux
linux /vmlinuz-linux
initrd /intel-ucode.img
initrd /initramfs-linux.img
options root=/dev/sda2 rw
```

But there's no such file:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate intel-ucode.img
[no output]
```

Kernel:

```
$ uname --kernel-release
3.16.4-1-ARCH
$ uname --kernel-version
#1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 6 08:22:27 CEST 2014
```

**What did I miss?**

Comment: Kernel version?

Comment: it doesnt seem to me like the bootloader should have much relevance to cpu microcode. i say this because the microcode is applied by the linux kernel - and at that point whatever bootloader you are using has already fulfilled its purpose. besides, im pretty sure gummiboot is a boot manager - not a loader - which means  it provides a menu and returns your selection to the firmware which does the actual loading of the selected os kernel. this means that if the loader is the problem youll want to look at firmware not gummiboot, but probably the solution lies in initramfs instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the warning on the Arch Wiki [microcode page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microcode):

> Warning: With linux 3.17-2 and linux-lts 3.14.21-2 and newer versions, Intel microcode updates are not triggered automatically any more.

The `intel-ucode` package will only install the `intel-ucode.img` to `/boot/` if you are running a 3.17.* kernel. Now that 3.17 has been moved to [core], upgrade with `pacman -Syu` and then reinstall `intel-ucode` and the image will get written to `/boot/`. Then your gummiboot configuration, which is correct, will work as advertised.

Comment: Had to upgrade to get kernel 3.17 (didn't need to reinstall `intel-ucode`; it was upgraded at the same time), and then it worked as you said. Thanks!